# SASS - Nest child of both it's parent and another of it's parent's children

Tags: css, sass, nested, css-selectors, flexbox

I am building a flexbox grid and would like to have an element (columns) be a child in both it's direct parent (grid) and another one of the parents children (nested).

My question: Is there a SASS method that would accomplish this while keeping it DRY? Current implementation looks like this:

```
.grid{
  ...

    .nested{
      ...

        .columns{
          ...
        }
    }

    .columns{
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: .grid, .nested { ??  to set commun properties

Comment: Yeah, that would be the solution I was going to aim for if there was not any thing sass-specific. (I think I am overthinking it and ignoring Occam's Razor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the one outside `.nested`.

It will compile to `.grid .columns` which will work for all `.columns` inside `.grid` including those inside `.grid .nested`.

However if you for some reason need to have `.grid .nested .columns` too, you could do this:

```
.grid{
    ...
    .nested{
        ...
    }
    &, .nested {
        .columns{
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first set styles for `.grid .column` and after that adding necessary styles for `colums` inside a `nested` element. Therefore you are DRY because those will cascade the styles for `.grid .columns`